# How to get recursive tables data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I have three tables
`Categories`, 
`Websites`, `Categorywebsites`

Category table has fields:

```
id | parent_id | name
```

Website table has fields:

```
id | name
```

Categorywebsites table has fields:

```
id | website_id | category_id
```

I would like to fetch parent Categories with their child categories and their corresponding categorywebsites and then their websites details corresponding to categorywebsites in single array.

I have defined the relationship in category model

```
public function categories(){
 return $this->hasMany('Category','parent_id','id');
}

// To get categories website linked to category.
public function categorywebsites(){
    return $this->hasMany('Categorywebsite');
}

public function websites(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Website');
}
```

I am using this code to fetch all the data in Hierarchy But i am getting

```
Array(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [parent_id] => 0
        [cat_name] => Search Engine
        [categories] => Array
            ([0] => Array([id] => 6
                        [parent_id] => 1
                        [cat_name] => PPC
                        [websites] => Array
                            ([0] => Array(
                                        [id] => 1
                                        [website_id] => 1
                                        [category_id] => 6
                                    )[1] => Array
                                    ([id] => 2
                                     [website_id] => 2
                                     [category_id] => 6
                                   )[2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 3
                                        [website_id] => 3
                                        [category_id] => 6
                                    )
                                  )
                                )
```

First my motive is also get website detail with categrywebsites subarray.I would like to fetch data using one query.This process make the system slow.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

If the reading action to your database is slow, just add ->remember(5) to your sql statement, where 5 means to remember the selection result for 5 minutes. Of course, it is assumed that your category content will not change constantly. Caching content will dramatically improve performance.

As for your other questions, I do not understand what you want. Maybe you can paste the subarray that you desire, so I can help you construct the exact sql statement.

Hope this helps.